# Importing data from DLP through API in PowerBI, getting error " Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: ssl, powerbi, tls1.2

I am trying to connect PowerBI with Symantec DLP through API but when I am trying to connect DLP API through Web option I am getting error:

> "Details: "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

I have API, user id and Password provided by Symantec DLP team but nothing is working.

Could anyone suggest how to overcome this issue in PowerBI.

Symantec DLP, or Data Loss Prevention, is a cybersecurity solution that detects and prevents data breaches. Since it blocks extraction of sensitive data, organizations use it for internal security and regulatory compliance